# Grunt Watch task repeating steps unnecessarily

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm new to Grunt.js. I've been working on a micro project that aims to produce a single .html file that is very portable without any external dependencies. It will have CSS and Javascript within the HTML document but I'd like to work on the project with external sass and js files while using grunt tasks to assemble the final .html file with each change.

As a result I'm "watching" all scss, js, and html file changes. When **any** file changes I need to rebuild the html file (also using `grunt-includes`). It's all working right now, technically. But it seems like some tasks are repeating. I'm out of my league reading this accurately so I'm interested in:

1. Is there a way I can avoid multiple passes over the same tasks?
2. With this being my first pass at a grunt task set, is there anything completely off / backwards in my code so far as you can tell (happy to provide more info as needed)?

My grunt.js file contents:

```
    module.exports = function(grunt) {
    "use strict";
    require("matchdep").filterDev("grunt-*").forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        includes: {
            files: {
                src: ['build/*.html','build/*.css','build/*.js'],
                dest: './',
                flatten: true,
                cwd: '.',
                options: {
                    silent: true,
                    includePath: 'build/includes'
                }
            }
        },
        concat: {
            fields: {
                src: ['build/fieldTypes/*.html'],
                dest: 'build/includes/fieldTypes.inc.html',
                options: {
                    separator: '\n\n\t<hr/>\n\n\n'
                }
            },
            js: {
                src: ['build/js/ga.js', 'build/js/core.js'],
                dest: 'build/includes/scripts.inc.js',
                options: {
                    separator: '\n\n'
                }
            },
        },
        sass: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed',
                sourcemap: 'none'
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    flatten: true,
                    src: 'build/sass/styles.scss',
                    dest: 'build/includes/',
                    ext: '.inc.css'
                }]
            }
        },
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: 'build/**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass', 'includes']
            },
            js: {
                files: 'build/**/*.js',
                tasks: ['concat', 'includes']
            },
            html: {
                files: 'build/**/*.html',
                tasks: ['concat','includes']
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
};
```

The log after a change:

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "build/fieldTypes/Dropdown.html" changed.
Running "concat:fields" (concat) task
File "build/includes/fieldTypes.inc.html" created.

Running "concat:js" (concat) task
File "build/includes/scripts.inc.js" created.

Running "includes:files" (includes) task

Done, without errors.
Completed in 0.631s at Sun Apr 12 2015 09:54:20 GMT-0400 (EDT) - Waiting...
>> File "build/includes/fieldTypes.inc.html" changed.
>> File "build/includes/scripts.inc.js" changed.
Running "concat:fields" (concat) task
File "build/includes/fieldTypes.inc.html" created.

Running "concat:js" (concat) task
File "build/includes/scripts.inc.js" created.

Running "includes:files" (includes) task

Done, without errors.
Running "concat:fields" (concat) task
File "build/includes/fieldTypes.inc.html" created.

Running "concat:js" (concat) task
File "build/includes/scripts.inc.js" created.

Running "includes:files" (includes) task

Done, without errors.
Completed in 2.022s at Sun Apr 12 2015 09:54:22 GMT-0400 (EDT) - Waiting...
>> File "build/includes/fieldTypes.inc.html" changed.
>> File "build/includes/scripts.inc.js" changed.
Running "concat:fields" (concat) task
File "build/includes/fieldTypes.inc.html" created.

Running "concat:js" (concat) task
File "build/includes/scripts.inc.js" created.

Running "includes:files" (includes) task

Done, without errors.
Running "concat:fields" (concat) task
File "build/includes/fieldTypes.inc.html" created.

Running "concat:js" (concat) task
File "build/includes/scripts.inc.js" created.

Running "includes:files" (includes) task

Done, without errors.
Completed in 2.111s at Sun Apr 12 2015 09:54:24 GMT-0400 (EDT) - Waiting...
```

I appreciate the time and assistance.

Comment: Question (1): My gut tells me that the `grunt watch` is watching *all* html files, **including the concat-ed/built ones**. The "files" part of the "watch" task is what you likely want to change. Also, question (2) is not a good fit for stackoverflow - it isn't answerable, per se.

Comment: Thanks @rosshamish. Your response is ironic because 1) you provide a possible _answer_ and 2) suggest it isn't answerable. :) I'll experiment with the watched file match. Thanks!

Comment: Haha. Fair enough. Good luck!

Comment: @rosshamish actually I just re-read your initial comment. You're totally right. Revised response: 1) I'll experiment with the watched file match. 2) Good call. Edited my original post. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @rosshamish I found my solution. I was watching files incorrectly: too global and not specific enough on the tasks being run. My revised `grunt.js` file limited my watching to less files and only ran the necessary tasks after specific changes.

**tl;dr: I wasn't being specific enough in file matching and task running.**

Part of the problem was that I was watching all html, css, and js files in the entire `build` directory rather than just the primary files I needed to watch. My first change was the following:

```
includes: {
    files: {
        src: ['build/*.html','build/*.css','build/*.js'],
```

to

```
includes: {
    files: {
        src: ['build/*.html'],
```

After all, I only had `include "file.ext"` blocks in the top level .html files of the build directory. I was overreaching at first.

Next up I refined other tasks by further specifying file matching more properly. Lastly, I update the `watch` task with the more specific triggers.

The original `watch` was the following:

```
watch: {
    css: {
        files: 'build/**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass', 'includes']
    },
    js: {
        files: 'build/**/*.js',
        tasks: ['concat', 'includes']
    },
    html: {
        files: 'build/**/*.html',
        tasks: ['concat','includes']
    }
}
```

And I updated it to this:

```
watch: {
    css: {
        files: 'build/sass/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass', 'includes']
    },
    js: {
        files: 'build/js/*.js',
        tasks: ['concat:js', 'includes']
    },
    fieldTypes: {
        files: 'build/fieldTypes/*.html',
        tasks: ['concat:fields', 'includes']
    },
    core: {
        files: 'build/*.html',
        tasks: ['concat','includes']
    }
}
```

The final `grunt.js` file contents are:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    "use strict";
    require("matchdep").filterDev("grunt-*").forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        includes: {
            files: {
                src: ['build/*.html'],
                dest: './',
                flatten: true,
                cwd: '.',
                options: {
                    silent: true,
                    includePath: 'build/includes'
                }
            }
        },
        concat: {
            fields: {
                src: ['build/fieldTypes/*.html'],
                dest: 'build/includes/fieldTypes.inc.html',
                options: {
                    separator: '\n\n\t<hr/>\n\n\n'
                }
            },
            js: {
                src: ['build/js/ga.js', 'build/js/core.js'],
                dest: 'build/includes/scripts.inc.js',
                options: {
                    separator: '\n\n'
                }
            },
        },
        sass: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed',
                sourcemap: 'none'
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    flatten: true,
                    src: 'build/sass/styles.scss',
                    dest: 'build/includes/',
                    ext: '.inc.css'
                }]
            }
        },
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: 'build/sass/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass', 'includes']
            },
            js: {
                files: 'build/js/*.js',
                tasks: ['concat:js', 'includes']
            },
            fieldTypes: {
                files: 'build/fieldTypes/*.html',
                tasks: ['concat:fields', 'includes']
            },
            core: {
                files: 'build/*.html',
                tasks: ['concat','includes']
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
};
```